# Cisco IP SLA snmp notifications

Tags: networking, cisco

I have a ruleset on a Cisco IOS router similar to the one below. All works great with regards to the delay on the track however the SNMP bits trigger in the event of a single ICMP failure and not in the event of a track timer completing and finding a changed state on the track and thus changing the route.

I can see the track timer is working as expected: "Reachability is Up, delayed Down (12 secs remaining)"

How should it be configured to trigger on a failure which causes the floating route to activate?

```
track 1 rtr 123 reachability
 delay down 20 up 60
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.2.3.4 track 1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 4.3.2.1 254 name ADSL_Backup
!
ip sla 123
 icmp-echo 3.4.5.6 source-interface FastEthernet0/0
 timeout 2000
 frequency 10
ip sla schedule 123 life forever start-time now
!
logging trap notifications
!
event manager applet IP-SLA-123-TIMEOUT
 event snmp oid 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.9.1.6.123 get-type exact entry-op eq entry-val 1 exit-op eq exit-val 2 poll-interval 5
 action 1.0 mail server "7.6.5.4" to "me@mail.com" from "monitor@mail.local" subject "IP SLA 123 Timeout" body "Timeout on the primary line"
event manager applet IP-SLA-123-OK
 event snmp oid 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.9.1.6.123 get-type exact entry-op eq entry-val 2 exit-op eq exit-val 1 poll-interval 5
 action 1.0 mail server "7.6.5.4" to "me@mail.com" from "monitor@mail.local" subject "IP SLA 123 Restored" body "Primary line restored"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are triggering SNMP alert using the Cisco EEM based on the IP SLA feature, not the track object.

Have a look at this documentation instead: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4t/12_4t2/ht_eem.html#wp1058361

Comment: That looks much more like what I need. Thanks.

I'll give it a failure test out of hours and let you know :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Had to change the secondary route to use a stub track as the route's metric made it take affect too soon.

Comment: @phil-lavin No probs, your very welcome :)